# Django annotate more than one field

Tags: python, django

ideally I want to create an annotation that Counts more than one field. Here is the code:

```
#the model
class Referral(models.Model):
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
     region = models.ForeignKey(Region)
     owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner')
     receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='receiver')
     company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     note = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True)
     timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


 #I know how to get either owner or recipient, but how to annotate owner + recipient combined?
 users = User.objects.annotate(num_referrals=Count('owner')).order_by('-num_referrals')[:3]
```

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: do you want to sum the count of owner and receiver together? or just want to annotate together?

Comment: I want to Sum them, yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
users = User.objects \
        .extra(select={'total': 'Count(owner)+Count(receiver)'}) \
        .order_by('-total')[:3]
```